# Setting grafana.ini via Terraform Helm provider

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I'm able to install grafana using the `stable/grafana` chart, using Terraform and the Helm provider. I'm trying to configure grafana with a new grafana.ini file, which *should* be possible using a `set`, however it doesn't appear to pick up the configuration at all.

I've also tried using the Helm release resources [values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/release.html#values) key to merge in the same config in yaml format (with a top-level `grafana.ini` key), also with no success.

What I'm trying to achieve is a file containing my config, in ini or yml format, passed to the grafana Helm chart so I can configure grafana correctly (ultimately I need to configure OAuth providers via the config) using Terraform.

Relevant config snips below.

- Chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana
- Terraform v0.12.3
- provider.helm v0.10.2
- provider.kubernetes v1.8.0

*grafana.ini*

```
[security]
admin_user = username
```

*main.tf (excerpt)*

```
resource "helm_release" "grafana" {
  chart = "stable/grafana"
  name = "grafana"

  set {
    name = "grafana.ini"
    value = file("grafana.ini")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found the correct way of merging the values key - it turns out (no surprise) I had the format of grafana.ini wrong when converting to YAML. Here's the working config:

*config.yaml*

```
grafana.ini:
  default:
    instance_name: my-server
  auth.basic:
    enabled: true
```

*main.tf*

```
resource "helm_release" "grafana" {
  chart = "stable/grafana"
  name = "grafana"
  values = [file("config.yaml")]
}
```